# How to allow a SQL Login to see only ONE database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

i have a SQL Server server 2008 r2. I wish to create a two new Login for a client who wishes to have access to their one database. But I don't want to give them access to the other my databases.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: T-SQL

```
 USE [master]
 GO
 CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[xyz],      
 CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
 GO
 EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'test', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
 GO
```